# Actualizar datos - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

actualmente estoy intentando actualizar unos datos de una tabla, en la tabla tengo varios campos y uno de ellos se llama CLIENTID que es el ID del cliente, dicho ID es único pero en algunos casos me arrastre CLIENTDID que no son los correctos por ejemplo:

En una tabla que tengo que se llama CustomerContractRelation el ID del cliente X es 2
En otra tabla que tambien trabaja con el mismo Clientid ya no es 2 ya es 101520 que es el correcto

Entonces lo que quiero es que me los clientes que tengo en mi table si el CLIENDTID es 2 que me valide en las tablas que mencione arriba si tiene el correcto

Por ejemplo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero actualizar el campo "CLIENTID ACTUAL" por el id que esta en otra tabla, el query que estoy usando en este momento es el siguiente:

```
SELECT 
bp.BPId,
bp.BPTypeCode,
bp.DocNum,
bp.ClientId AS [CLIENTID ACTUAL],
COALESCE(bpr.ClientId,bpr.OuterClientId) AS [CLIENTID QUE DEBERIA DE MOSTRAR]
FROM  dbo.TempTransaccionesBP bp
INNER JOIN CWCORE2.CWNET_HON.dbo.BPClientsRelations bpr ON bpr.BPId = bp.BPId
WHERE bp.BPId IN ('611852888','611852976','611853043','611853047','611853070','611853072')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se si entendí bien lo que necesitas. Si lo que quieres es actualizar la columna `ClientId` de la tabla `TempTransaccionesBP` con la información de la columna `Clientid` o `OuterClientId` (la primera no nula) de la tabla `BPClientsRelations` vinculando por las columnas `BPId`, lo puedes hacer así:

```
UPDATE bp
SET bp.ClientId = COALESCE(bpr.ClientId, bpr.OuterClientId) 

FROM TempTransaccionesBP bp
INNER JOIN BPClientsRelations bpr ON bp.BPId = bpr.BPId
```

Si solo quieres realizar el update cuando ClientId = 2, agrega la cláusula where al final: `WHERE bp.ClientId = 2`.

Comment: Funciono perfecto, muchas gracias

Comment: De nada @MarcoTulio!